# Efficient algorithm/data structure that maps tic-tac-toe boards to floats

Tags: group-theory

I'm implementing a q-learning agent for tic-tac-toe that requires mapping from tic-tac-toe boards to float values. Since certain game states are equivalent and should have the same value, it would be more efficient to store all games that are mirrors or $90^{\circ}$ rotations of each other, only once. Is there an algorithm/data structure to efficiently store/lookup elements with $D_4$ symmetric group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign every cell a ternary digit among cross/dot/empty and encode the games using nine-trits numbers (base-3 digits). Base-4 can also do.

Now every time you want to encode a game, generate all 8 symmetries and compute the 8 corresponding numerical codes. Finally, keep the encoding with the lowest value. That will ensure uniqueness.

E.g.

[image]

Is encoded as the smallest of x--oox--o, -ox-o-ox-, o--xoo--x, ... (trits from top to bottom, left to right).

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to compute minimum encoding? This solution works but computing all values seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @MahdiKhodabandeh: bottleneck ? That takes less than microseconds. And as there are less than 3^9 configurations, you can precompute all.

Comment: Yes, In a compiled language this should be less than microseconds; but I'm using python for the ml libraries. Even though rotations and flips were done using NumPy, surprisingly doing these millions of times became a bottleneck. Using a lru_cache seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Source code if you are interested: https://github.com/khoda81/tictactoe-q-learning.

Comment: Which millions of times ?

Comment: Training takes about 10000 games and each game is about 10 steps long. We train ai 10 times on each game. So we perform about a million updates on this mapping which is one read and one write. This is why I needed this to be efficient.

Comment: Even so, I doubt that the encoding of the games would be the time consuming part of the process.

Comment: Interestingly, the (well-known) winning strategy is coded in a few lines. Or AI beaten by common sense.